# Use DrawerLayout and FlyOutContainer

Tags: android, flyout, drawerlayout

I have a problem, I would like to put in my Layout the Drawer Layout and the FlyOutContainer but in the error Log it shows an error:that DrawerLayout cannot be cast to FlyOutContainer what can I do to fix this problem. I need the Drawer Layout to go to the MainActivity.

Hope you can help me and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: It would help if you explained what FlyOutContainer if (or provided a link to it)...

Comment: Or post the stack trace from Logcat

Comment: https://github.com/jaylamont/AndroidFlyOutMenuDemo/tree/part1/FlyOutMenuExample

Answer (score 1):

The code in that demo inflates a layout and casts the root view of the Layout to FlyOutContainer. If you change your layout xml so that the root is now DrawerLayout, then that code no longer runs correctly and you are probably getting ClassCastException. You should do it this way instead (in onCreate()):

```
setContentView(R.layout.your_activity_layout);
DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout_id);
FlyOutContainer flyOutContainner = (FlyOutContainer) findViewById(R.id.fly_out_container_id);
```

Of course, if you don't actually need a reference to these views/layouts, you can just stop after `setContentView(...)`